# Chrony fails to sync with NTS enabled

Tags: ntp, chrony

I have configured Chrony server and client on two Centos 9 Stream machines. Without NTS everything is fine and the time is being synced. However, when I enable NTS, and configure the server to use certificate, the sync is failing. Any idea what the issue might be? Below is the server and client config:

Server:

```
[root@server1 ~]# cat /etc/chrony.conf
pool 2.centos.pool.ntp.org iburst
sourcedir /run/chrony-dhcp
driftfile /var/lib/chrony/drift
makestep 1.0 3
rtcsync
allow 192.168.11.0/24
keyfile /etc/chrony.keys
ntsdumpdir /var/lib/chrony
leapsectz right/UTC
logdir /var/log/chrony

ntsserverkey /etc/certs/chrony.key
ntsservercert /etc/certs/chrony.crt
```

```
[root@server1 ~]# cat /etc/chrony.keys
1 MD5 AVeryLongAndRandomPassword
```

Client:

```
[root@client1 ~]# cat /etc/chrony.conf
sourcedir /run/chrony-dhcp
driftfile /var/lib/chrony/drift
makestep 1.0 3
rtcsync
keyfile /etc/chrony.keys
ntsdumpdir /var/lib/chrony
leapsectz right/UTC
logdir /var/log/chrony
server server1 iburst nts
```

```
[root@client1 ~]# cat /etc/chrony.keys
1 MD5 AVeryLongAndRandomPassword
```

Sync test:

```
[root@client1 ~]# chronyd -Q -t 3 'server server1 iburst nts maxsamples 1'
2022-08-06T23:23:52Z chronyd version 4.2 starting (+CMDMON +NTP +REFCLOCK +RTC +PRIVDROP +SCFILTER +SIGND +ASYNCDNS +NTS +SECHASH +IPV6 +DEBUG)
2022-08-06T23:23:52Z Disabled control of system clock
2022-08-06T23:23:52Z TLS handshake with 192.168.11.29:4460 (server1) failed : The TLS connection was non-properly terminated.
2022-08-06T23:23:55Z chronyd exiting
```

When checking the capture, it seems that the server terminates the connection after receiving the client hello:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the certificate used by your NTS server trusted by your client? I tried to reproduce your configuration and I was able to get things working.

### Server setup

I started by generating a self-signed certificate for use by the server:

```
server# cd /etc/chrony
server# openssl req -x509 -nodes -newkey rsa:4096 \
  -keyout chrony.key -out chrony.crt \
  -sha256 -days 365 -subj /CN=server1
```

I configured the server like this:

```
pool 2.centos.pool.ntp.org iburst
sourcedir /run/chrony-dhcp
driftfile /var/lib/chrony/drift
makestep 1.0 3
rtcsync
allow 192.168.11.0/24
keyfile /etc/chrony.keys
ntsdumpdir /var/lib/chrony
leapsectz right/UTC
logdir /var/log/chrony

ntsserverkey /etc/certs/chrony.key
ntsservercert /etc/certs/chrony.crt
```

I started the server in debug mode to test it out and saw an error
("Could not set credentials").

```
server# chronyd -d
2022-08-08T00:54:52Z chronyd version 4.2 starting (+CMDMON +NTP +REFCLOCK +RTC +PRIVDROP +SCFILTER +SIGND +ASYNCDNS +NTS +SECHASH +IPV6 +DEBUG)
2022-08-08T00:54:52Z Frequency 0.765 +/- 3.876 ppm read from /var/lib/chrony/drift
2022-08-08T00:54:52Z Could not set credentials : Error while reading file.
2022-08-08T00:54:52Z Using right/UTC timezone to obtain leap second data
```

The error was caused by the permissions on `/etc/certs/chrony.key`,
which was owned by root and mode `0600`. I made it owned by the
`chrony` user:

```
server# chown chrony /etc/certs/*
```

Now when I start `chronyd -d` on the server it runs without errors.

### Client setup

On the client, I used your config file:

```
sourcedir /run/chrony-dhcp
driftfile /var/lib/chrony/drift
makestep 1.0 3
rtcsync
keyfile /etc/chrony.keys
ntsdumpdir /var/lib/chrony
leapsectz right/UTC
logdir /var/log/chrony
server server1 iburst nts
```

When I first tried start `chronyd -d`, I saw the following error:

```
2022-08-08T01:01:06Z TLS handshake with 192.168.122.17:4460 (server1)
failed : Error in the certificate verification. The certificate is NOT
trusted. The certificate issuer is unknown.
```

That's expected, since I'm using a self-signed certificate. To fix
that, we can install the certificate as a trusted certificate. On my system (Fedora, which should match your CentOS system), that means installing it into `/etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors` and then running `update-ca-trust`:

```
client# cat > /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/server1.crt
<paste certificate here>
^D
client# update-ca-trust
```

Now when I run `chronyd -d` I don't see any errors. Additionally, the client successfully connects to the server:

```
2022-08-08T01:03:36Z Selected source 192.168.122.17 (server1)
```

And running `chronyc -N authdata` shows:

```
client# chronyc -N authdata
Name/IP address             Mode KeyID Type KLen Last Atmp  NAK Cook CLen
=========================================================================
server1                      NTS     1   15  256   45    0    0    8  100
```

Comment: Thank you @larsks. In my case, the CA certificate is trusted by the client. Actually before posting the question, I tested with self-signed certificate as well. In that case, I am receiving a different error: `2022-08-07T00:28:11Z TLS handshake with 192.168.11.29:4460 (server1) failed : Error in the certificate verification. The certificate is NOT trusted. The certificate chain uses not yet valid certificate.`

When checking the capture, this time server does send Server Hello and Change Cipher Spec, but the Server Certificate is missing!

Comment: `[root@client1 ~]# ll /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/selfsigned.crt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1801 Aug  7 03:21 /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/selfsigned.crt
[root@client1 ~]# update-ca-trust
[root@client1 ~]# chronyd -Q -t 3 'server server1 iburst nts maxsamples 1'
...skipping...
2022-08-07T00:28:11Z Disabled control of system clock
2022-08-07T00:28:11Z TLS handshake with 192.168.11.29:4460 (server1) failed : Error in the certificate verification. The certificate is NOT trusted. The certificate chain uses not yet valid certificate.
2022-08-07T00:28:14Z chronyd exiting`

Comment: This all worked for me. It's not clear from your comments what you've done that's different. I've repeated this test on a pair of centos 9 hosts and it worked fine there, also. The only way I can generate the "The TLS connection was non-properly terminated." is by having an incorrect `allow` configuration on the server, causing it to reject the client and terminate the connection.

Comment: Larsks if you still have this setup, could you please check if the sync stops in case of key mismatch?

Comment: What do you mean by "key mismatch"? You mean e.g. `chrony.key` on the server isn't the appropriate key for `chrony.crt`? In that case `chronyd` will fail to start with `Could not set credentials : The certificate and the given key do not match.`.

Comment: No, I mean the key defined in chrony.key on the server is different than the one defined in chrony.key on the client. Now my client is syncing with the server with NTS configured but the sync is still successful with different keys.

Comment: I believe that static keys (as configured with `keyfile` and the `server ... key ...` option) are unused when you have configured NTS security.

Comment: You are right. NTS and SK (Symmetric Keys) are two different types of NTP security. Thank you so much.